# Google Drive downloading file with same content

Tags: jquery, google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to select two images from my google drive and trying to download the content in base64 as shown and sending it to my server side to download the file on to my server folder but after downloading I'm able to get the two files but with same content. I'm not sure where I'm doing mistake..Can anyone solve me this issue?

For single image its working fine..The problem is when I select more than 1 file.
Sometimes when selected 2 files and one file gets downloaded and other not and sometimes with 403 error..NO problem documentation on google for api v3.

```
 "error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
            "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
        }
    ],
        "code": 403,
            "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded"
}
```

Code to get the data:

```
 function pickerCallback(data) {
    var fileId;
    var gdriveids = [];
    var gdrivebas64 = [];
    var selectedfilenames=[];

    if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
            fileId = data.docs[i].id;
            gapi.load('client', function () {
                gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function () {
                    var file = gapi.client.drive.files.get({ 'fileId': fileId, fields: '*' });
                    file.execute(function (resp) {
                        console.log(resp);
                        var maxFileSize = 20971520/*20MB(20*1024*1024)*/;
                        filesize = resp.size;
                        displayfilesize = formatBytes(filesize);
                        filesizes.push(displayfilesize);
                        morefiles = maxfiles - imgcount;
                        if (gdriveids.length > morefiles) {
                            $('#filelist').html("You can add only " + morefiles + " more file(s).");
                            $('#myProgress').show();
                        } else {
                            if (filesize < maxFileSize) {
                                $('#myProgress').show();
                                $('.images').html("");

                                console.log("FolderName : " + inputFolderName);
                                console.log("Files : " + selectedfilenames);

                                var accessToken = oauthToken;
                                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + '?alt=media', true);
                                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
                                xhr.onload = function () {
                                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                        var base64 = base64ArrayBuffer(xhr.response);
                                        gdrivebase64.push(base64);

                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: "POST",
                                            url: "test.aspx/GetFile",
                                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                                InputFolderName: inputFolderName, FileNames: selectedfilenames, Base64: gdrivebase64
                                            }),
                                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (msg) {
                                                if (msg.d == "True") {
                                                    console.log("Success");
                                                } else {
                                                    console.log("Failed");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        $('#filelist').html('Error! Please try again.');
                                    }
                                }
                                xhr.send();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if all your problems will be solved by this, but you're making the `ajax` request with data from all previous iterations' files (`gdrivebase64`, `selectedfilenames`) in every subsequent iteration. This way, the data of the first file will be sent twice. I'm thinking you would actually want to make this request after and outside the `for` loop, or provide only the current file's data when making the `ajax` request, not an array with all of them (`gdrivebase64`, `selectedfilenames`). Can you please check that?